# What methods are available for parsing HTML?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What different ways are available for parsing html in WP7?

Comment: What is the meaning of your numbered list?  Presumably, if a library is available (such as HtmlAgilityPack) it will also be a "parser" and will also be composed from classes...

Comment: I honestly did (and don't) understand what you are talking about.  If a parser exists it will simulataneously be a library, a parser, and composed of one or more classes.  And finally, **I wasn't the one who voted to close, so please cease with your belligerent attitude!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) will work. You have to download the source and look in the Truck for the HAPphone code and then compile the dll yourself, but it works. It doesn't include the full capabilities of the overall code, but works reasonably well.

Comment: @JnJDev I tried to use it but it said it wasn't made using the WP7 runtime. How can I use it?

Comment: Built it properly here, try this http://www.filedropper.com/htmlagilitypackwp7-77494