# How to parse Html to get the Image with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using WebClient to download the html of a webpage. How to parse to get the Image Tag and the image's src so that I can download the image. Thanks for your help.

--- Update 
I downlaoded the HtmlagilityPack. I got this error msg when I used Add reference in my windows phone project:

HtmlAgilityPAck is not built using windows phone runtime. Windows Project will work only with windows phone assemblies

How to solve this issue so I can use the webclient as follows? Thanks.

```
var client = new WebClient();   
client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;  
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(strUrl));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to grab the source code for `HtmlAgilityPack` and build the HAPPhone project. You can reference the resulting assembly in your WP7 project. [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6601214/63225).

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded one from http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com but the DLL not working. But now I downloaded this one from:http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets, this one has what you mentioned. I just copies all the cs files into my existing project or just create a new project with all these cs files and compile to get the DLL which use it in existing project? Thanks